# What's the meaning of "Making demands on someone" in the following context?

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs, collocations

> She (Julie) spent her time doing little more than taking care of him (Mark) and the children. Now her sister was getting divorced and would doubtless be making
> demands on her too.

Does it mean that her sister needs help with the housework after the divorce? Am I get it?

Comment: [Collins Dictionary:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-demands) **make demands** - *If someone or something makes demands on you, they require you to do things which need a lot of time, energy, or money.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She expects that her sister will be needing help in the future; probably not particularly with housework, but emotional support and, if the sister has children, perhaps help with childcare.